# How to add user level environment variables to be used by GUI application?

Tags: 12.04, environment-variables

What is the recommended way to add user level environment variables to be used by a **GUI application** in Ubuntu? I know there are ~/.bashrc, ~/.cshrc, ~/.profile etc for console apps.

1. How can I add new paths to existing PATH (/bin:/usr/bin/:/usr/X11R6/bin/usr/local/bin)?
2. How to add settings (new key value pairs)? This is meant to be used by a bunch of applications.

Answer (score 0):

At [EnvironmentVariables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Session-wide_environment_variables), `~/.pam_environment` and `~/.profile` are mentioned as suitable files in Ubuntu. Personally I prefer `~/.profile` since it's a script file.